# django-cms: define a placeholder in a template without automatically showing it

Tags: python, django, templates, django-cms

I want to create a template that has some content

```
{% placeholder content %}
```

plus some "teaser" content that I want to display on another page, but not on the page that uses this specific template. Obviously, the page that displays the content does not need a teaser for it.

I'm using cmsplugin_filer and the solution I found seems way too complex:

In my template I'm defining the teaser placeholder as follows:

```
{% with skipteaser=True %}
    {% placeholder teaser %}
{% endwith %}
```

and then overide the cmsplugin_filer template as follows:

Instead of

```
<div{% if instance.style %} class="{{ instance.style }}"{% endif %}>
<h2>{{ instance.title }}</h2>
{% if instance.image or instance.image_url %}
    {% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if obj.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{% endif %}
        {% if instance.image_url %}
            <img alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ instance.image_url }}"{% if instance.width or instance.height %} style="{% if instance.width %}width:{{ instance.width }}px;{% endif %}{% if instance.height %}height:{{ instance.height }}px;{% endif %}"{% endif %} />
        {% else %}
            {% thumbnail instance.image size crop upscale subject_location=opts.subject_location as thumbnail %}
            <img alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ thumbnail.url }}" />
        {% endif %}
    {% if link %}</a>{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if instance.description %}
<p>{{ instance.description }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if obj.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{% trans "more" %} &#187;</a>{% endif %}
</div>
```

I use:

```
{% if skipteaser %}
{% else %}
    <div{% if instance.style %} class="{{ instance.style }}"{% endif %}>
    <h2>{{ instance.title }}</h2>
    {% if instance.image or instance.image_url %}
        {% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if obj.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{% endif %}
            {% if instance.image_url %}
                <img alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ instance.image_url }}"{% if instance.width or instance.height %} style="{% if instance.width %}width:{{ instance.width }}px;{% endif %}{% if instance.height %}height:{{ instance.height }}px;{% endif %}"{% endif %} />
            {% else %}
                {% thumbnail instance.image size crop upscale subject_location=opts.subject_location as thumbnail %}
                <img alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ thumbnail.url }}" />
            {% endif %}
        {% if link %}</a>{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if instance.description %}
    <p>{{ instance.description }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if obj.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{% trans "more" %} &#187;</a>{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

so that the teaser does not show in the page that uses the template, but I can invoke it in other pages with

```
{% show_placeholder "teaser" other_page %}
```

this seems too complex. Isn't there a way for me to define a placeholder in a template without automatically showing it?

Comment: Did you got any solution for that?

Comment: I still use the solution described in my initial post. Its not so bad after all... I doubt there's anything simpler...